# Escaping variables in Smarty strings

Tags: smarty

I want to put the name of a variable inside a string, so that I can later define the variable, before the string is evaluated to become the value of the variable. How can I do this?

A few different attempts:

```
{assign var="test" value="$foo"}
{assign var="foo" value="bar"}
{eval var=$test}
```

Result: Undefined index: foo

```
{assign var="test" value="{$foo}"}
{assign var="foo" value="bar"}
{eval var=$test}
```

Result: Undefined index: foo

```
{assign var="test" value="\{$foo}"}
{assign var="foo" value="bar"}
{eval var=$test}
```

Result: Undefined index: foo

```
{assign var="test" value="\$foo"}
{assign var="foo" value="bar"}
{eval var=$test}
```

Result: $foo

```
{assign var="test" value="{\$foo}"}
{assign var="foo" value="bar"}
{eval var=$test}
```

Result: Syntax error

```
{assign var="test" value="\{\$foo}"}
{assign var="foo" value="bar"}
{eval var=$test}
```

Result: \bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: Using single quotes!

```
{assign var="test" value='{$foo}'}
{assign var="foo" value="bar"}
{eval var=$test}
```

Result: bar